# tc don't see marked packets

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, tc

Server has 2 interfaces:

- eth1 with address 13.0.0.254/24
- eth0 with address 172.20.203.4/24.

It's routing traffic between this two networks. Task is to limit bandwidth between this two networks to 1Vbit/sec, but not to limit bandwidth between server and network hosts(i. e. limit all packets going though FORWARD)

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 13.0.0.0/24 -d 172.20.203.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x0001
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.203.0/24 -d 13.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 0x0002

# eth1
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1:0 htb default 2

tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 999mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 1mbps

tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 2:0 sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:3 handle 3:0 sfq perturb 10

tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 handle 1 fw flowid 1:3
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 handle 2 fw flowid 1:3

# eth0
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 2

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1000mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 999mbps ceil 1000mbps
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 1mbps

tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 2:0 sfq perturb 10
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 3:0 sfq perturb 10

tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 handle 2 fw flowid 1:3
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 handle 1 fw flowid 1:3
```

This doesn't work. If I use this at the beginning:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1:0 htb default 3
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb default 3
```

it works. So problem is in filter settings.

```
iptables -L -v -n -t mangle
```

shows, that packets are going though MARK rules. I tried to mark packets not in POSTROUTING, but in FORWARD or PREROUTING - this does not work too. What am I doing wrong?

Here is some diagnostics:

```
# tc -s -d -r filter show dev eth0
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw handle 0x1 classid 1:3
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw handle 0x2 classid 1:3
# tc -s -d -r filter show dev eth1
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49151 fw handle 0x2 classid 1:3
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw
filter parent 1: protocol [768] pref 49152 fw handle 0x1 classid 1:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modprobe xt_mark
```

If module is not loaded, iptables gives no f***ing error, but rules "-j MARK" do not work